# Mysql, How to read auto increment value in other fields of the same inserting row?

Tags: php, mysql, database, insert, auto-increment

Hello I need to have the transaction id in the comment field of my transaction

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `transactiontb` (`tid`, `amount`, `comment`) VALUES (NULL,'$amount', CONCAT('Transaction # ',`tid`)')");
```

How can i do this?

Comment: You already have the number in `tid` column. Why on earth would you need it in comments once more is beyond me.. people just like stupidly complex solutions, don't they?

Comment: I will not show every transaction id to users , just in some types of transaction the user need to know his tid and then he will read it from comment, i can update the comment with another query but i'm looking for a shorter way

Comment: So dynamically build the comment when selecting and displaying.

Comment: The user can edit comment and this is a default value for the comment

Comment: @N.B. Simply, if you would like to make data migration script. Namely, if you would like to migrate data to Drupal, you may find fields such as vid has the same value of nid in the node table.

Comment: @sємsєм if I would like to make a data migration script, I don't need more than 1 column to hold one and the same value. I also wouldn't use Drupal so I still claim there is no valid reason to use a relational database and to repeat a value needlessly. But humans are not logical beings so I understand that we like stupid solutions and that we often don't pause and think before doing things.

Comment: The most thing may surprise you is that one of the most popular CMS do that behavior in its database schema! However, it is conditional case there. i.e if all of Drupal's nodes does not has any revisions. @N.B.

Comment: @sємsєм I don't know why we're discussing this matter at all. I don't care about Drupal and its popularity. Any repetition **without reason** is by *definition* stupid. I also don't see any mention of Drupal in the question, I seriously have no clue why you're bringing this matter up anyway, your comments aren't helping at all to steer people towards right solution and now we're discussing some piece of software that has nothing to do with the question. Also, smart engineers don't give themselves more work, so they don't repeat data/values for no reason. Remember that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Get off of mysql_* functions.  Look at MySQLi or PDO.
2. Don't store the `tid` twice.  Why not concat when you select it instead of storing it that way? This is not the best way.

For reference though, try `LAST_INSERT_ID()+1)`:

```
INSERT INTO `transactiontb` (`tid`, `amount`, `comment`)
VALUES (NULL, '$amount', CONCAT_WS('Transaction # ', LAST_INSERT_ID()+1))
```

`LAST_INSERT_ID()` will give the ID of the previous INSERT not the one from the current INSERT so you must add 1.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id

> The ID that was generated is maintained in the server on a
>   per-connection basis. This means that the value returned by the
>   function to a given client is the first AUTO_INCREMENT value generated
>   for most recent statement affecting an AUTO_INCREMENT column by that
>   client. This value cannot be affected by other clients, even if they
>   generate AUTO_INCREMENT values of their own. This behavior ensures
>   that each client can retrieve its own ID without concern for the
>   activity of other clients, and without the need for locks or
>   transactions.

Comment: I afraid that sometimes LAST_INSERT_ID(id+1) is not equal to current insert id

Comment: And what would make you afraid? Have no fear, without the +1 you will get the previous record not the current one. But I updated with a better +1.

Comment: But still, this is a horrible way of storing data.

Comment: Your code works but in every insert just returns 1 and when i delete +1 it will return 0 so i will see Transaction # 0

Comment: Using `LAST_INSERT_ID()+1` ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` function.

> LAST_INSERT_ID() (with no argument) returns a BIGINT (64-bit) value
>   representing the first automatically generated value that was set for
>   an AUTO_INCREMENT column by the most recently executed INSERT
>   statement to affect such a column.

Source: [MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)

Example:

```
"INSERT INTO transactiontb(tid, amount, comment) VALUES (NULL,'" . $amount . "', CONCAT_WS('#','Transaction',LAST_INSERT_ID(id+1)))"
```

Just saw you were also forgetting to put the separator for you `CONCAT_WS` function, so i fixed it in the example query.

Comment: I have used but couldn't get result , can u give me an example ?

Comment: Check the answer for an example.

Comment: You were also forgetting to use the separator in the CONCAT_WS function, so i've updated that too.

Comment: '# Transaction' is just a string , anyway the code you wrote is not working , is it the right syntax of using LAST_INSERT_ID() ?

Comment: You had `'# Transaction'` as your first value, the first value in `CONCAT_WS` is the `SEPERATOR`, look it up in the mysql documentation. and yes, this query is supposed to be correct. Are you sure you copied after my last edit?

Comment: @Amin Gholibeigian Oh wait, damn, it was my fault haha, sorry, forgot a ) at the end, will edit it for the final time!

Comment: Without the +1 you will get the previous record not the current one.

Comment: Damn it will insert zero even i use just LAST_INSERT_ID() , i think we cant use this function in inserting fields

Comment: So  why this returns zero ehrn my last tid is 52